# How to calculate the exact sum of two floats in javascript

Tags: javascript

As we know, in Javascript 0.1 + 0.2 does not return 0.3 - it returns 0.3000000004.
I have a problem while I am building a calculator in Javascript.
Usually, we use the `toFixed()` function to format a number using fixed-point notation.
But on a calculator, we can not expect the number of digits to appear after the decimal point.
So how can I solve this problem?

Comment: mistake - Javascript

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - This exact same issue exists in Java too - :-)

Comment: Do you have any idea about how to solve that issue?

Comment: If you're open to using a library, this will do the trick https://www.npmjs.com/package/two-sum

Comment: Actually, on a calculator you *can* expect the number of significant digits: it's how many fit on your screen. If you have only 10 or so, floating point double precision will suffice.

Comment: "*0.1 + 0.2 does not return 0.3 - it returns 0.3000000004.*" - actually it's 0.30000000000000004